# jQuery validation error message location

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation plugin to check my inputs, and having troubles of adjusting the location of the error messages. Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/godhong/USsrw/1/) of my code.

I would like to show the error message under the problematic cell, not next to it. I checked the reference and found I should focus on the `errorPlacement` function. So if I would like to display the error message under the cell, should I create an new `<tr>` and then insert the error message? Thanks for any suggestions.

```
$("#myform").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );
   },
   debug:true
 })
```

Comment: do you have to use a <table> for your <form>?

Comment: I can change `<table>` to `<div>`, but that requires to change a lot more stuffs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only reason the error message is "next" to the element is because both are inline elements (`<select>` and `<label>`).  You can move the error message underneath by simply:

1) Targeting the error label with some CSS that gives it a `display: block;`

or

2) Wrapping the error label in some block element before inserting it (you can use the code you posted above and just wrap the error in a div before appending it)

Comment: I tried the first approach. It works, but not lined up properly... Is there a way to make sure the size of error message has the same size of examined cell? Thanks!

Comment: I mean the error messages are floating around and change the layout of current format of input cells. But it seems like using `white-space: nowrap` solves the problems a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `display:block` to your CSS. Works for me.

```
.error{
    border-color: #F78181;
    color:red;
    display:block;
}
```

To make the `label` the same width as the `select`, you can [style it with CSS next sibling's nomeclature `+`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector) like this:

```
select + label{
    width:300px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: If the error message is too long, then it could not automatically wrap. I think using `white-space: nowrap` could solve this issue.